# How to add TabHost to a LinearLayout bu code in android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

For my android application I need to implement a tabView within a LinearLayout. I could able to add textview and button to the LinearLayout like this,

```
public CreateView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setText("Submit");
    button.setLayoutParams(llp);
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("This is a test");
    tv.setLayoutParams(llp);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addView(tv);
    this.addView(button);}
```

In my Activity class I added these as,

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends Activity {
LinearLayout ll;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);

    ll.addView(new CreateView(this));
    setContentView(ll);

}
```

}

I want to do the same thing for a tabview. But I couldn't able to find a way to add tabHost to my lineaLayout. any way to do this??
thanx

Comment: why do you want to do this programmatically, not by xml? Looks like quite some overhead to me.

Comment: bcz this is for a server-client app. Want to draw the interface dynamically.Can't have a predefined XML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining the TabHost in xml and adding tabs programmatically with tabHost.newTabSpec like it's shown in tutorial, the following structure is created:

```
LinearLayout
     TabHost>
          LinearLayout
               TabWidget
               FrameLayout
                   LinearLayout for tab 1
                   LinearLayout for tab 2
                   ...
```

I guess you need to replicate this nesting in code.
The root-LinearLayout in the xml-version has width and height set to fill_parent and orientation to vertical. Maybe that's also required for it to work.

Comment: Why it is giving an error saying that "The method getTabHost() is undefined for the type Linearlayout" ??

Comment: No, am extendig a LinearLayout and trying to use addView() to add the new tabHost inside it. I'm using a separate Activity class and there I have set that LinearLayout as in above code.
any help pls?

Comment: why do you need getTabHost() if you create and add it manually? In case you want to reference it from the Activity, you could get it as usual with findViewById() I guess.

Comment: I dnt knw the exact method to do this. What I want is to implement a tabView dynamically. For sure I can't have an xml file. I must do this with java. So didi, I think I can't use findViewById function here.any other option?

Comment: I think findViewById() also works for views created programmatically. You can assign id's to views with method setId().